# aiohttp nested applications and passing app data

Tags: python-3.6, aiohttp

I am trying out aiohttp (to test against Flask, and just to learn it) and am having an issue with passing data via the Application. The examples say that I can set a key value in the `app` in order to pass static info (e.g., a database connection).  But, somehow this information is getting lost and I suspect it is in the nested applications, though not sure.

`app.py`:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web
import logging

from data import data_handler
from data import setup_web_app as data_setup_web_app

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger('data')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

async def my_web_app():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)

    app['test'] = 'here'

    data_setup_web_app(web, app)

    return app
```

`data.py`:

```
from aiohttp import web
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger('data')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def setup_web_app(web, app):
    data = web.Application()
    data.add_routes([web.get('/{name}', data_handler, name='data')])
    app.add_subapp('/data/', data)

async def data_handler(request):
    name = request.match_info['name']

    log.debug('test data is {}'.format(request.app['test']))

    return web.json_response({'handler': name})
```

And I am using gunicorn to run it: `gunicorn app:my_web_app --bind localhost:8080  --worker-class aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker --workers=2`

But when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/data/asdf` in the browser I get a `KeyError: 'test'` in the `data.py` debug print statement.

I suspect the app data is not being passed through correctly to the nested applications, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Now keys from main app are not visible from subapp and vise versa.

Please read the [issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/2689) for more details.

I'd like to support a kind of chained map for this but the feature is not implemented yet.